# Child records from relation don't load  (EF4.0, POCO)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have 2 classes: **User** and **Booklink**

```
        public class User
        {
            public int UserID { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Login { get; set; }
            public string Surname { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Points { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }

            public IEnumerable<BookLink> BookLinks { get; set; }
        }

        public class BookLink
        {
            public int LinkID { get; set; }
            public int BookID { get; set; }
            public int UserID { get; set; }
            public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }

            public Book Book { get; set; }
            public User User { get; set; }

        }
```

I used new EF4.0 feature - POCO.

The problem: when I load **user** entity  BookLinks property is **NULL** (there are some child records in Booklinks table). But other fields(properties) was loaded fine and all of them (except Booklinks) have their values from database.

I receive objects from generic repository like this:

```
UsersRepository usersRepository = new UsersRepository();

            User user = usersRepository.FindByID(1);
```

FindByID method is implemented like this

```
private ObjectSet<T> _entitySet;    
return _entitySet.AsQueryable().Where(predicate).SingeOrDefault();
```

And navigation property Booklinks in **user** instance  is NULL

I cant understand why I see this behaivour. How I can load child records automatically?

Here is screenshot from EF designer http://tinyurl.com/2ct45d5 (if it will help...)

Comment: I set ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true

but my problem was not solved :-(

Answer (score 2):

Lazy loading can't work on a POCO unless you declare your association `virtual` (you haven't) and enable proxy creation (the default, IIRC).

Comment: I set "ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;" and marked BookLinks collection as virtual - "public virtual IEnumerable<BookLink> BookLinks { get; set; }"

But my problem was not solved. Booklinks propery is still NULL.

Comment: You must also enable LazyLoading as well. Its one of the option on the ContextOptions

Comment: I solved my problem by this:
public virtual ICollection<BookLink> BookLinks { get; set; }

But I cant understand are there huge differencies between IEnumerable and ICollection?

Comment: That makes sense. You (and, perhaps more importantly, the EF) can't add to an IEnumerable.